# How to generate a random number

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have to create a test for homework using Selenium IDE and create a scenario to generate a random number. I'm struggling with what I need to type and what field to type in.

What should I type in?:
Command
Target
Value

Comment: What language? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you can generate random numbers in Selenium: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161984/using-selenium-ide-with-random-values

Answer (score 20):

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [wisc.edu](https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/lnmaurer/web/minirng/Dilbert0001.jpg))</sub>

Comment: AH hahaha what a perfect response.

Answer (score 3):

i always use this to create random username and e-mails

```
storeEval > Math.round (Math.random() * 1357) > random
type > id=UserName > selenium${random}
```

and

```
storeEval > Math.round (Math.random() * 1357) > random
type > id=UserEmail > selenium${random}@am.com
```

i hope they can help you

Answer (score 1):

I use this often in my JUnit tests to create random inputs values.

```
int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * MAXVALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int num = rand.nextInt(range);
```

Range is the max number you want to return. Num will be something between 0 and range.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Random rndNum = new Random();    System.out.println("Num "+rndNum.nextInt());
```

for a single number like: Num -1597641332

or try

```
Random rndNum= new Random();    int rndNum1 = 0;

   for (int nbr = 1; nbr <= 3; nbr++) {
       rndNum1 = rndNum.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Number: " + rndNum1);    }
```

for multiple number of random numbers like

Number: -1891834125
Number: -1541629941
Number: -129634738