# Selenium: Get unique value?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Just using selenium to fill out some forms for me. I need it to generate a unique value for my username field. How can I do that?

I've got

**Command:** type
**Target:** id_of_my_field
**Value:** username+unique_value ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use javascript to do that:

> **Value**: javascript{'username'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)}

This will append a 6 digit random number to your username.

See [this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161984/using-selenium-ide-with-random-values) for more details and other ways to do this...

Comment: Darn it. I was trying `javascript:`. Didn't know about the `{}` syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution which works well for me:

Save the following TEXT as a .js file and add to the Options->Options "Selenium Core Extensions" list...

```
Selenium.prototype.doTypeRandomName = function(locator) 
{
  /**
  * Sets the value of an input field to a random "name" 
  * as though you typed it in.
  */
  // All locator-strategies are automatically handled by "findElement"
  var element = this.page().findElement(locator);

  /* The following block generates a random name 8 characters in length */
  var allowedChars = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var stringLength = 8;
  var randomstring = '';

  for (var i=0; i<stringLength; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedChars.length);
    randomstring += allowedChars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
  }

  // Replace the element text with the new text
  this.browserbot.replaceText(element, randomstring);
}
```

Once done, you can simply select the `TypeRandomName` command in Selenium for each text box where you want a random "name" to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for a globally reusable solution is as follows

1) Download sideflow.js from [Download here](https://github.com/darrenderidder/sideflow)

2) Add following lines into it :

```
Selenium.prototype.doTypeRandomName = function(locator) {
    /**
     * Sets the value of an input field to a random email id,
     * as though you typed it in.
     *
     * @param locator an <a href="#locators">element locator</a>
     */

    // All locator-strategies are automatically handled by "findElement"
    var element = this.page().findElement(locator);

    /* The following block generates a random email string */
    var allowedChars = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    var stringLength = 8;
    var randomstring = '';

    for (var i=0; i<stringLength; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedChars.length);
        randomstring += allowedChars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }

    // Replace the element text with the new text
    this.browserbot.replaceText(element, randomstring);
};
```

3) Save the file

4) Go to Selenium ide -> options -> options ->Selenium Core extensions -> give reference of your file there.

5) Now your randomname function will appear in auto-intellisense and will be as "typerandomname" command category.

6) Sample usage could be (if base url is google.com)

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>typerandomname</td>
    <td>css=input[class='gbqfif']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to generate unique numbers without using JavaScript in your code: (i used Java)

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddHHmmss");            /* Here you create object of the class DateFormat, and SPECIFY THE FORMAT (ddHHmmss). (Don`enter code here`t forget to import class Date(ctrl+shift+o  if you are using Eclipse)) */  
    Date date = new Date();                                              /* Here you create object of the class Date. (Dont forget to import class Date. (Dont forget to import class Date(ctrl+shift+o  if you are using Eclipse)) */  
    String random_number = dateFormat.format(date);                      /* Assign your current Date(something like 19184123) (ddHHmmSS) to a local variable(it require a String) */  
    yourWebDriver().findElemnt(By.cssSelector("input#someId")).sendKeys("test"+random_number+"@tester.com");    /* send keys to your input injecting random number */
```

Such method will give truly unique number that will never repeat itself, because it use your current time...

You can add even further randomness if include mile seconds into DateFormat

Comment: This will fail in scenarios where numbers are generated back-to-back. Even including more detail (fractions of seconds) is likely to fail due to lack of precision.