# How to execute Javascript in Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I can execute html script and html suite through RC. Now I would like to execute javascript through Selenium RC. I have few question related to this.

1. Should I need to set class path for that?
2. After writing test script in javascript, what is the format of javascript suite. Please provide example.
3. What will be the comment to execute the suite from command prompt? I think the command I used to execute html suite may not work. The command I used java -jar selenium-server.jar -multiwindow -javaSuite "*iexplore" "http://www.google.co.in/" "C:\Tests_suite.html" "C:\results.html"

Answer (score 1):

The way I've used Javascript with Selenium RC id to use the [User extensions](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.html#using-user-extensions-with-selenium-ide).

There's some info. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161984/9922) as well.

Or you can use the [getEval](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#executing-javascript-from-your-test) method of selenium API to execute Javascript from Selenium RC.

From the command line, remember to add:

> -userExtensions : indicates a JavaScript file that will be loaded
>   into selenium