# Dynamic data in Selenium IDE tests?

Tags: selenium

Can I insert dynamic data into the tests that Selenium IDE produces, or do I need to do this with Selenium Server?  For example, I'd like to insert the current date and time into a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking the same thing as this question: [Using Selenium IDE with random values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161984/using-selenium-ide-with-random-values)

In any case, using javascript, you can get the current date and time and use that within your test