# Fuzz test (framework) web application?

Tags: javascript, testing, web-applications, fuzzing, random-testing

Are there frameworks that can perform fuzztesting on WebApplications? I know that `Selenium` and `WebDriver` are used to build tests for web-applications, but I am particulary interested in libraries, frameworks or projects that have fuzz-testing built-in, so I do not need to re-invent the wheel.

For example, I could benefit from these features:

- randomized link clicking
- randomized form filling
- 'back' and 'forward' clicking
- random mouse movement and clicking
- javascript support

Does anyone know of project that implements these features? (preferably Java :))

Comment: @DannyBeckett  please advise on how to improve? I was considering building my own, but wanted advice on exists solutions, and I think more people might benefit from this knowledge.

Comment: I don't agree with the downvote on this question at all; it's a perfectly valid question.  I have +1'd it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was curious about this as well since we use Selenium/Java here at my office, and did some digging of my own.  I found a few links that may be useful to you:

[Fuzz Testing - IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-fuzztest/) - I suspect you may have already found this link though.

[Monkey Fuzz Testing](http://monkeyfuzz.codeplex.com/) - I know, I know... it's .NET.  BUT, it may give you some good ideas as to how to implement it on your end.

[Stephen Coldebourne's Blog](http://blog.joda.org/2004/11/testing-security-permission_5894.html) - This was a great read; well worth your time.

[JBroFuzz](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_JBroFuzz_Tutorial#How_to_Use_JBroFuzz_as_a_Fuzzing_Library) - This is pretty awesome.  That is all.

Answer (score 9):

As the post tagged "javascript", I'm adding here [Gremlins.js](https://github.com/marmelab/gremlins.js) which is a testing/fuzzing framework written for Node and browsers. Surprised no one mentioned it yet.

[image: Gremlins.js preview]

Comment: Also, great name for a project :)

Answer (score 2):

Some new JS Fuzz testing NPM modules now existing. Sadly, many are not widely used, so expect them to need some polish or TLC.

- [fuzzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzer)
- [sorrow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sorrow)
- [javascript-fuzz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-fuzz)
- [fuzzur](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzur)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is (now = September 2013) almost no general purpose Fuzz testing tool using Selenium. But luckily you could implement your own specialized fuzz tool.

Requirements:

- Knowledge of [Selenium RC/WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)
- Some programming skill in a [language](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_What_about_support_for_languages_other_than_Java?) that Webdriver supports
- Good structure of your HTML elements, so that you could easily focus your fuzzing. One good practice, regardless the old (messy ?) structure of your HTML pages, is to add a specific id, e.g. selenium-id to your HTML element, to (1) simplify XPath formation, (2) speed up XPath resolution and (3) to avoid translation hassle. While choosing the value for these newly added selenium-id, you are free to help iterating while fuzzing by (a) using consecutive numbers, (b) using names that forms a consistency.

I have written more extensively on this Fuzz Selenium test [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650990/how-to-do-fuzzing-testing-with-selenium)