# How to pass the random & unique data in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

In my application, there is email id field & which is unique i.e. duplicate email id application can't accept.

Now my problem is how can i pass random but unique email id in my application. i know this is easy in webdriver but my requirement is IDE.

Comment: You can try to use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161984/using-selenium-ide-with-random-values/3616176#3616176) to generate random values in IDE.

Comment: i don't understand why -1. thanks patrick l for your direction.

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but this might help you for next time: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask