# Chrome Selenium IDE random number generator

Tags: google-chrome, random, selenium-ide

I saw similar topics but nothing exact.

When I used Firefox and the IDE I was able to use **StoreEval | Math.round (Math.random() * 99999999999)** to create a random number of a specific length.  I have now moved to Chrome to use the IDE and "StoreEval" is no longer an option. I have tried all the new "store" options available but end up with the below warning in the logs and the number is not created:

"Warning implicit locators are deprecated, please change the locator to id=Math.round (Math.random() * 99999999999"

Any ideas on what I need to use/change?  I will admit I am not exactly sure what "please change the locator to" means.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You must use **execute script** command in the last version of Selenium IDE.

1. Right click on any command, and select "Insert New Command"
2. Insert the following. The result will be stored in `myRandomNumber`

   ```
   Command : execute script

   Target : return Math.random()

   Value : myRandomNumber
   ```
3. You can then reference this variable in the Value of any Command, using `${myRandomNumber}`

**Note:**
You can also see your generated random number. To do so, add another Command:

```
Command : echo

Target : ${myRandomNumber}
```